# nohup command & : How to discard output?

Tags: linux, bash, nohup, dev-null

I am running this command :

`nohup google-chrome > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

After I run it I get this output :

`[1] 16975`

Is there anyway that I can run that command and get no output at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The apparent output you get is part of the job-control of the shell. To suppress the shell's job-control output, you need to run the command in a sub-shell as explained in the linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `&>` to redirect both stdout and stderr like so:

```
nohup google-chrome &> /dev/null &
```

To hide the pid use a subshell:

```
(nohup google-chrome & ) &> /dev/null
```